# Comparing differences across a rebase in Git

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-diff

Suppose that I just rebased the branch `foo` on `master`, with conflicts. I want to make sure that I did not accidentally damage the content of `foo` during conflict resolution by introducing extra changes or losing changes (other than that which is appropriate for the conflict resolution). I have done this via:

```
diff -u <(git diff `git merge-base master foo@{1}` foo@{1}) \
        <(git diff `git merge-base master foo    ` foo    )
```

(update: or the equivalent `...` syntax for `git-diff` which I have just been reminded of:)

```
diff -u <(git diff master...foo@{1}) <(git diff master...foo) | mate
```

This shows me all the changes that have occurred to *`master..foo` considered as a patch*, which is exactly what I want to check for being minimal. However, the invocation is complex and the output is not entirely straightforward to interpret.

Is there a better way to accomplish this task — to provide the same information, but with a better method or format — or should I just take the above and wrap it up in a script?

Comment: Isn't this essentially equivalent to `git diff foo@{1} foo`?

Comment: @twalberg No; `git diff foo@{1} foo` shows both my conflict resolutions and the changes made to master that I rebased onto, rather than just the conflict resolutions.

Comment: Ah, right... I was only considering my own most common rebase case, in which the merge-base of the source and destination stay the same (rewriting/squashing a branch before pushing).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304574/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-an-equivalent-commit

Comment: The question title is relevant also to comparing by only the subject of commits, so that "nearly-equivalent" commits show up (that wouldn't even with `git cherry`). `git log` with a diff viewer is an option in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127413/1959808

Comment: With Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), don't forget `git range-diff @{u} @{1} @`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956712/6309).

Answer (score 17):

Even better than `interdiff`, now with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) you have `git range-diff`.
See "[Git diff - two disjoint revision ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956694/6309)"

The [`git range-diff` documentation includes the following example](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81eab6871e03869a8e47799c10ec1e1cb95ca34a/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt#L89-L142):

> When a rebase required merge conflicts to be resolved, **compare the changes introduced by the rebase directly afterward** using:
>
> ```
> $ git range-diff @{u} @{1} @
> ```
>
> A typical output of `git range-diff` would look like this:
>
> ```bash
> ------------
> -:  ------- > 1:  0ddba11 Prepare for the inevitable!
> 1:  c0debee = 2:  cab005e Add a helpful message at the start
> 2:  f00dbal ! 3:  decafe1 Describe a bug
>     @@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
>       Author: A U Thor <author@example.com>
>
>     -TODO: Describe a bug
>     +Describe a bug
>     @@ -324,5 +324,6
>       This is expected.
>
>     -+What is unexpected is that it will also crash.
>     ++Unexpectedly, it also crashes. This is a bug, and the jury is
>     ++still out there how to fix it best. See ticket #314 for details.
>
>     Contact
> 3:  bedead < -:  ------- TO-UNDO
> ------------
> ```
>
> In this example, there are 3 old and 3 new commits, where the developer:
>
> - removed the 3rd,
> - added a new one before the first two, and
> - modified the commit message of the 2nd commit as well its diff.
>
> When the output goes to a terminal, it is color-coded by default, just like regular `git diff`'s output.
> In addition, the first line (adding a commit) is green, the last line (deleting a commit) is red, the second line (with a perfect match) is yellow like the commit header of `git show`'s output, and the third line colors the old commit red, the new
> one green and the rest like `git show`'s commit header.

---

With Git 2.20, colors are better supported for the new kind of (range) diff

See [commit 2543a64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2543a64187bb80078e493268e683cb0661be754f), [commit 8d5ccb5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d5ccb59def8c1737b3e055a5984eaaa4e881ce9), [commit 7648b79](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7648b79eeefc23e773a41b24e3ecdadb9fe93643) (17 Aug 2018), and [commit 4441067](https://github.com/git/git/commit/444106791ee2c4c4575db439ef74d5db5ede6a27), [commit f103a6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f103a6faef97b062aa039d8e6c361340cfd8bc02), [commit 29ef759](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29ef759d7ca039590240890a604be8308b30a069), [commit 017ac45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/017ac45e87074a51e7bf926b8f87152a1af9a441), [commit 9d1e16b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d1e16bf59cd35e1019e63b171ddf9209e0f53a1), [commit 84120cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84120cca09002453649abf40e1873c4041247d64), [commit c5e64ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5e64caaa9c45988b474765182a508f305f05e6b), [commit 991eb4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/991eb4fc6ab1942cbd86060da2846813d990459e) (14 Aug 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 30035d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30035d1d60053e2999041ca14ab607d40206e201), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `range-diff`: indent special lines as context

> The range-diff coloring is a bit fuzzy when it comes to special lines of a diff, such as indicating new and old files with `+++` and `---`, as it would pickup the first character and interpret it for its coloring, which seems annoying as in regular diffs, these lines are colored bold via `DIFF_METAINFO`.
>
> By indenting these lines by a white space, they will be treated as context
> which is much more useful, an example on the range diff series itself:
>
> ```
> git range-diff pr-1/dscho/branch-diff-v3...pr-1/dscho/branch-diff-v4
> ```

(from repository [`github.com/gitgitgadget/git`](https://github.com/gitgitgadget/git))

> ```bash
> [...]
>     + diff --git a/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt b/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt
>     + new file mode 100644
>     + --- /dev/null
>     + +++ b/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt
>     +@@
>     ++git-range-diff(1)
> [...]
>     +
>       diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
>       --- a/Makefile
>       +++ b/Makefile
> [...]
> ```
>
> The first lines that introduce the new file for the man page will have the
> '`+`' sign colored and the rest of the line will be bold.
>
> The later lines that indicate a change to the `Makefile` will be treated as context both in the outer and inner diff, such that those lines stay regular color.

---

> If I understand correctly, the top example could be rewritten as: `git range-diff @{u}..@{1} @{u}..@`, with `@{u}..@{1}` being considered the "older" (or reference) range.
> What guarantees that `@{1}` refers to the tip of the range of commits before the rebase?

`git range-diff` is designed to compare two sequences of commits (ranges), typically before and after a rebase or a merge operation.
The correct syntax for `git range-diff` does not involve range specifications like `@{u}..@{1}`. Instead, it directly compares two commit ranges by their specific identifiers or reflog entries.

`@{1}` refers to the state of the current branch one step back in its reflog. The reflog records changes to the tip of branches, allowing you to reference previous states of a branch. When you perform operations like rebase, merge, or even a simple commit, Git updates the reflog.
After a rebase, `@` (or `HEAD`) refers to the current tip of the branch, and `@{1}` refers to the state of the branch immediately before the rebase operation. That is because the rebase updates the branch's tip, causing the reflog to record the state of the branch before the rebase as the previous entry (`@{1}`).

- `@{u}..@{1}` and `@{u}..@` syntax is used for specifying ranges in `git diff` or similar commands, indicating a set of commits from a common ancestor with `@{u}` to `@{1}` or the current `HEAD`. However, this range notation does not align with how `git range-diff` expects its arguments.
- `git range-diff` compares two sequences of commits directly, *without* the `..` range notation. It expects identifiers that reference lists of commits or reflog entries, not commit ranges in the `start..end` format.

For `git range-diff`, you would typically use something like `git range-diff @{1} @{u} @`, where:

- `@{1}` refers to the state of your branch before the latest operation (e.g., rebase).
- `@{u}` might be intended to refer to the upstream branch, but the correct reference in this context is not as straightforward, since `@{u}` in `git range-diff` does not directly apply. Instead, you would compare the state of your branch before and after the rebase directly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the top example could be rewritten as: `git range-diff @{u}..@{1} @{u}..@`, with `@{u}..@{1}` being considered the "older" (or reference) range. What guarantees that `@{1}` refers to the tip of the range of commits prior to the rebase?

Answer (score 8):

What we really want to show is the conflict combined diff that is generated as if we had done a merge to get from (a) to (b) where (a) was previously based on (upstream-old) and (b) is now based on (upstream-new).

We don't want just a straight diff.

Instead, we can essentially do the merge but force the resulting tree to be $b^{tree} which we already know is the correct "end" point of what we want.

More or less, let's assume that we have

```
newcommit -> the new version of the series
oldcommit -> the old version of the series
upstream -> the (new) version of the base of the series
```

We can generate the merge via

```
git commit-tree newcommit^{tree} -p oldcommit -p upstream -m "message"
```

and then show the result with "git show" and this will generate a combined diff format that shows all the necessary bits as a conflict resolution which automatically ignores changes that weren't actually part of resolving conflicts.

This even works for simply ammending a change as well, and you can do a bit more work to ensure that the generated merge commit has exact author and commit timestamps so that it's consistent over multiple calls (since we *are* storing a loose ref into the object database).

Unfortunately I have not been able to figure out how to just get "git diff" to diff the same way without actually generating a tree yet. I'm not sure what arguments we'd have to pass to get to that point.

Comment: Clever idea! I'll have to see how useful the results are the next time I have this problem.

Comment: I just had an opportunity to try this out. I found a caveat that needs to be noted: `upstream` _deleted_ a file that had changes (so as to split it into several other files), and the diff produced by this technique does not mention that file at all, so would not show the loss of those changes.

Answer (score 3):

`git-cherry` searches for commits on one branch that aren't on another. You'd use it as:

```
git cherry -v OLDTIP TIP UPSTREAM
```

i.e. look for commits that were on `OLDTIP` but which aren't on `UPSTREAM..TIP`. It looks at the patch signature to see whether a patch is included, so if a patch got added, dropped or modified during the rebase then it will show up in the list. Things that got applied without changes won't appear.

A similar effect can be achieved by going back to `OLDTIP` and doing `git rebase -i TIP`, since that uses the same logic to populate the list of commits.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help with examining intra-file changes. I'm interested in hunk-level changes lost or damaged due to bad conflict resolutions, not whole commits.

Comment: The idea here is to reduce the number of commits you need to compare (ideally to zero). It's not useful if you have a small number of large, conflicting commits, but it might help with a large number of small commits.

Comment: Ah, I would guess, then, that by this standard I have a small number of large commits, because the follow-up question that came to mind is  “Once I have the commits to compare, how do you propose I compare them, other than performing the diff-diff I started with?”

Answer (score 2):

Differences between master and rebased foo:

`git diff master..foo`

vs.

Differences of pre-rebase foo after branching off master (note three dots):

`git diff master...foo@{1}`

?

Comment: Thanks, using `...` shortens the command, and I've actually used that before so I should have thought of it. However, I'm still left with explicitly comparing those two diffs themselves. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's s rebase and not a merge, you might want to compare `foo` with itself but before the merge. If I recall correctly `foo@{1}` will yield the parent of the current commit for `foo`, and maybe this is not what you are looking for.

I think you can do something like the following (assuming you haven't done a `git gc`):

On the branch `foo` after the rebase:

```
$ git reflog
```

This will show how your branch's HEAD has been moved. You should see some records like this (depending if you rebase interactively or not):

```
64d3c9e HEAD@{15}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
64d3c9e HEAD@{16}: rebase -i (fixup): Fixes external dependencies
049169e HEAD@{17}: rebase -i (fixup): updating HEAD
d4c2e69 HEAD@{18}: rebase -i (pick): Fixes external dependencies
049169e HEAD@{19}: rebase -i (fixup): Imports futures
e490bed HEAD@{20}: rebase -i (fixup): updating HEAD
...
etc
...
```

Look forward to the last of commit of `foo` before the merge. Depending on what you have done this may be difficult or not. That's why I have not provided a do-it script.

Pick up the commit id that have the last commit for `foo` before the rebase and then compare to that commit id. Say that commit id is: `XXXX`:

```
 git diff XXXX...foo
```

Maybe that's what you want.

Comment: As I responded to twalberg, this will not exclude the changes to  master which I rebased onto, and is therefore very noisy. (By the way, digging through HEAD's reflog is not necessary; the *branch*'s reflog will contain only the before and after states, and `foo@{1}` is exactly the commit you propose manually searching for. `@` looks into the reflog, not ancestry.)

Comment: @KevinReid You're right, I confused `@` with `~`. I don't use them often. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach: Git has good support for showing this in the case of merges. i.e. "what changed relative to parent-1 which can't be explained by parent-2?"

There are a couple of ways you could leverage that support for your rebase:

Option 1:

1. Do a throw-away merge first (instead of a rebase). Then the normal merge display will show what the merge changed. Check this is what you wanted.
2. Go back and rebase, and compare the rebased tip against the merge result - they should be identical.

Option 2 (if rebasing is easier than merging):

1. Do the rebase.
2. Use a graft to make it look like a merge locally/temporarily.

To do that, create a .git/info/grafts with a single line:

```
TIP UPSTREAM OLDTIP
```

Where TIP is the commit ID of your rebased branch and the others are the two desired parents (i.e. the two things you would have merged, had you been doing a merge). Then examine it as if it were a real merge.

I'm not sure about automating it; I tend to do this stuff with gitk open, because it makes comparing the right revisions easy (using the right-click menu).

If you really want to compare two diffs then you might want to look at interdiff(1), but I'm not sure how well it will cope with the base files being different.

Comment: Regarding option 1, in the cases where I want to make this check, a merge is highly likely to have *different conflicts* than a rebase, and in any case I am looking to verify the rebase that actually happened. Regarding option 2, I tried it and found that the view is cluttered with the changes introduced on master, which is exactly what I want to hide. I don't have `interdiff`, but its man page says “The diffs must both be relative to the same files.”

Comment: I have a similar answer for this that works for a series and is basically "just use commit-tree to generate the merge post-rebase by assuming the merge result should be whatever the tree of the finished rebase is 

This just lets us essentially do a merge from upstream into v1 and force the result to have the tree of v2. This then can be passed to git-show and it will produce the lovely combined format, without having to rely on grafts, and thus it can be automated.