# What to do when parent of branch was squashed?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, rebase, git-rebase

Ok, I have branch `feature/12`, it's more or less done, so I branch off it and start working on
`feature/13`, which depends on `feature/12`.

Code review happens and a few small changes are made to `feature/12`. So I apply those changes, then  squash against `master` into a single feature commit, as is protocol in the company (`git rebase -i master`).

Now back to `feature/13`, how do I consolidate `feature/13`'s history so there are no history conflicts against `feature/12` and `master`? Do I simply `git rebase`feature/12` and fix any conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just rebase against master.

Rebase will attempt to apply the unsquashed commits on top of the squashed one, and likely see conflicts (though independent or last ones will be recognized as already applied and automatically skipped). You can:

- simply fix the conflict as usual, which should result in no staged changes,
- recognize the old commit and `git rebase --skip` when it comes up, or
- since you are using interactive rebase, delete the old commits' `pick` lines from the `git-rebase-todo` file.

---

If you're feeling extremely cautious, and you'd like to make sure the rebase operation didn't accidentally add or remove any *changes* that you have on `feature/13`, you can diff the diffs from the pre-rebase version and now by using a command like this immediately after finishing the rebase operation:

```
diff -u <(git diff master...feature/13@{1}) <(git diff master...feature/13)
```

This does not give perfectly clean output — it will report differences in context lines, and [I don't know of a better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465184/comparing-differences-across-a-rebase-in-git) — but  will definitely show you any changes lost (or gained) due to rebase.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I simply `git rebase feature/12` and fix any conflicts?

That'll do it, but notice that the additional changes in `feature/12` that got merged are also in `master` now, too, and any conflicts have already been resolved there. It's also just plain cleaner to base your work on the production version of any dependencies. If it later turns out you need to rebase again off new work in `feature/12`, you'd have had to do that anyway.