# Github pull requests history

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

Is the history of the pull-requests preserved forever?

I could not find anywhere for how long the pull-requests history is being saved.

Comment: Yes, they are..  (You can verify this empirically by picking any mature repo on GitHub and taking a look at the closed PR history.)

Comment: Commits across force pushes question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684749/compare-old-and-new-versions-of-force-pushed-github-pull-request

Answer (score 1):

The pull-requests history is indeed preserved by github forever as long as the repo is not deleted.

Comment: Can you please share a link with this info?

Comment: I know this from my personal experience with github. But if you can't belive me feel free to ask trough a github ticket : https://github.com/contact

Comment: If I'm not wrong , but I might be , github was launched in March-April 2008 , so you could check a 9 years old repo to make sure. :)

Comment: How can I clone my repo with the pull-request history?

Comment: You merge your repo with the pull request you want and then you simply `git  clone`

Comment: I need a solution for backup my pull-request messages

Answer (score 1):

To see your Github closed Pull Requests on the UI interface:

1. Go to your repo
2. Click on "Pull Requests" tab
3. Change the filter parameter from "is:pr is:open" to "is:pr is:closed"
   Here's picture
   [Picture of Pull Request on GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr5dt.png)