# See old versions of a GitHub pull request as remote branches

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-remote

I am working on a project which is maintained in Git, with a central repository on GitHub. I often review pull requests with the help of a local copy. While Git itself doesn't know anything about “pull requests”, GitHub makes the information available in a separate branch namespace. I've configured Git to fetch pull requests with a configuration like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:octocat/hello-world.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pull/head/*
```

Then I can check out PR #42 with `git checkout origin/pull/head/42`. So far so good.

If a pull request has been force-pushed after my initial review, I often want to compare the version that I reviewed with the new version. I would like to have something like `origin/pull/head/42/1` referring to the latest commit before the first force-push, `origin/pull/head/42/2` referring to the latest commit before the second force-push, etc. (I don't mind the exact names.) Is there any way to do this?

The problem has two parts:

1. Get GitHub to tell me what the commit ID is for the pre-force-push tip of a pull request. This information appears on the web page (`https://github.com/octocal/hello-world/pull/42` says “… force-pushed the `mybranch` branch from COMMIT1 to COMMIT2”), but I can't find it in the [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#list-commits-on-a-pull-request).
2. Teach Git that a certain commit should appear with a certain remote branch name, which may or may not be trivial depending on how (1) is done.

Is there a configuration or helper program that can give me easy access to old versions of GitHub pull requests, without having to copy-paste the commit ID from the web page and give it a local branch name?

Comment: I don't think you can get the information from GitHub in a proper machine-digestible form. You could scrape it out of the web page. Once you do get the information, the only way to *use* it is to fuss with the `fetch` lines: don't put in a general "fetch all PRs", put in one specific "fetch this one PR using this local name", per PR per iteration. Not very pretty, but should work fine.

Comment: @Gilles - so did you find a way to do what you wanted? I'm facing the same problem, and I couldn't find any way to view older PR versions (let alone to compare between the versions)...

Comment: @kliteyn No. The best I can do is use the web page, expand all the “hidden items” bits, and read the shas from the “force-pushed the NAME branch from SHA” lines. Some of those lines are “force-pushed the NAME branch COUNT times, most recently from SHA” and in that case I don't know how to find the intermediate shas. For the shas you manage to find, `git fetch origin SHA` works (IIRC it didn't a few years ago, but nowadays it does, even for older pull requests where it didn't work then).

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Events API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#list-repository-events),  which lists actions that occurred on a repo, and returns events :

- each individual event has a [type](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/github-event-types#event-object-common-properties) : `PushEvent`, `PullRequestEvent`, `CreateEvent` ...
- and a payload, which depends on its type ; for example :

  - payload of a [PullRequestEvent](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/github-event-types#pullrequestevent)
  - payload of a [PushEvent](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/github-event-types#pushevent)

---

A partial answer with local data : your local refs are also logged in the `reflog`, you can also look at what you have in `git reflog origin/pull/head/42`.

Obviously : the limitation of that solution is that you only see the points where running `git fetch` on your local repo updated that reference ; if someone has force pushed 3 times between two of your `git fetch`, your local reflog won't get updated 3 times.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this. It's a nice idea, but unfortunately, it doesn't work in practice. As far as I can tell, you can only get the most recent 300 events. For the project I'm most interested in, pull requests normally come from a fork (so you have to list the events from the fork), but even in a personal fork, most contributors are active enough that 300 events doesn't last nearly as long as a pull request. It's annoying that the information is mostly available on the web page (except with consecutive force-pushes), but i can't find it in the API.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried using your local reflog ?

Comment: The reflog only tells me about commits that I've pulled, and in practice that misses enough updates that it's not all that useful. Hmmm, now that I think of it, if I haven't pulled an update, then I probably haven't reviewed it, so for my use case it might be enough. I'll give a try at scripting that. Thanks for the ideas, in any case.

Comment: additionally : when you review a PR, you may place a tag stating "I reviewed that PR in that state"