# How to compare two git branches and filter the differences by commit message?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-commit, git-flow

I have a release branch named `release/X.X.X.X` which contains all feature branches I want to deploy to production. The release branch is made on top of `master` which is the current state of production.

On every release day I make sure our release branch contains only those changes planned for the release. I use this command to compare the release and master branch: `git log release/X.X.X.X ^master --no-merges`. I then manually check the commits for keywords like "SHR-1234" which represent ticket numbers in our ticket management system. I need to compare each commit with a list of ticket numbers to identify unwanted changes.

How can I filter commits that are returned by `git log release/X.X.X.X ^master --no-merges` and **do not contain** keywords like "SHR-1234"? This way I can identify the ticket number of unwanted changes.

I tried grep and awk but the results are not useful because they don't filter out the whole commit.

Comment: See `git log --grep`, then see the `--invert-grep` option.

Comment: @torek Used 1000 times indirect via gui but didn't know about it tbh :D Thank you! Can you add it as a answer so I can accept it? I use it like this `git log release/X.X.X.X ^master --no-merges --invert-grep --grep='SHR-1234' --grep='SHR-4321' ... `

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419623/1959808

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304574/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-an-equivalent-commit

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465184/comparing-differences-across-a-rebase-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`git log` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) provides two interesting options here:

> `--grep=<pattern>`
>          Limit the commits output to ones with log message that matches the
>    specified pattern (regular expression). With more than one
>    **`--grep=<pattern>`**, commits whose message matches any of the given
>    patterns are chosen (but see **`--all-match`**).
>
> When **`--show-notes`** is in effect, the message from the notes is
>    matched as if it were part of the log message.

Hence `--grep` lets you find commits that *do* contain some particular string or pattern.  You want commits that *do not* contain (any or all) strings, so we move on to:

> `--invert-grep`
>          Limit the commits output to ones with log message that do not match
>    the pattern specified with **`--grep=<pattern>`**.

(Incidentally, note that `release/X.X.X.X ^master` can also be spelled `master..release/X.X.X.X`.  There's no machine-level reason to prefer one over the other—both wind up doing exactly the same thing internally—so use whichever you find more readable.)

Comment: great, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use –G ‘regular expression’ to meet your requirement

`git log release/X.X.X.X ^master--no-merges -G ‘regular expression’` (include or exclude the specified commit)

Comment: `-G` searches for an expression that would show up in the *patch* as an added or removed line, i.e., it depends on `git diff` output. There is also `-S` which searches for a change in the *number of occurrences* of a string (unlike `-G` this searches for a fixed string, rather than a regex, unless you add more flags). However, the OP wants to search the *commit message* text.

Answer (score 0):

The question title admits a slightly different answer, which could be useful to some people. A simple way to compare two branches by commit title *only* is to dump commit titles from each branch to a separate text file, and open these two files in a diff viewer:

```sh
git --no-pager log --pretty=format:%s main > log_main.txt
git --no-pager log --pretty=format:%s other > log_other.txt
meld log_main.txt log_other.txt
```

We first dump commit subjects from branch `main` to the file `log_master.txt`, then commit subjects from branch `other` to the file `log_other.txt`, and open them in the visual diff viewer [`meld`](https://meldmerge.org) (one alternative is [`kdiff3`](https://apps.kde.org/kdiff3/)).

Comment: This doesnt help the OP at all; This wont't be any different then him saying `git log OTHER ^master` .   His problem is trying to identify certain commits with messages he doesnt expect; this doesnt reduce or solve the problem at all....  Ironically the problem is you focused on the title and not the content of the question.

Comment: Indeed, it leads to the same differences as `git log --pretty=format:%s other ^master`. One use of this approach is to see a comparison of where the commits that aren't contained in both branches are located with respect to other commits.

Comment: You are missing the point... there won't be any commits in `master` that aren't in `other` here that OP is concerned with.   `other` is ahead of `master` from when it was 'branched off ' for his version.   There is no order to compare, just a list of commits that are only on `other` and OP wants to find commits in there that shouldn't be there.... when finished OP will be merging back to `master`..  which again is why there's nothing to order.  You are answering a question that wasn't asked, why not ask and answer the question you keep trying to answer; that would likely be useful to others :)