# Git diff - two disjoint revision ranges

Tags: git, git-diff

I would like to select precisely some disjoint commits using the `git diff` command.

Here is an example. The commits are disposed on a one-branch tree, starting with A (the oldest commit), and ending with Z (the most recent commit):

```
A 
|
B
|
C
|
D
|
...
|
Y
|
Z
```

I would like to select two ranges of commits, B-D and O-Q (included), and use them with `git diff`. This can be made with two commands:

```
git diff B^..D
git diff O^..Q
```

**Is it possible to do it using only one `git diff` command**, in order to have only one output? Just imagine that O reverts D, it is helpful not to have O and D described separately.

Comment: I don’t quite understand what your output would look like. The diff of a commit range is essentially the difference between the start and the end of the commit range. Do you want a diff ``B^..Q``, excluding the diffs introduced by the commits between ``D`` and ``O``?

Comment: Exactly: all changes in `B^..Q` without the ones between `D` and `O`. Just imagine that all 6 commits are about a part of the project that is modified by no other commits in the tree. `D` introduces changes that are reverted by `O`. With two `diff` commands, `O` and `D` are separated, introducing noise into the output. With one command, the changes introduced by `D` should be hidden by `O`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be possible with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018, three years later) with the [new **`git range-diff`** command](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81eab6871e03869a8e47799c10ec1e1cb95ca34a/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt).

```
git range-diff B..D O..Q
```

This is inspired by [`trast/tbdiff`](https://github.com/trast/tbdiff), by Thomas Rast and Thomas Gummerer.

See [commit a7be92a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7be92acd96007bcb4c1fd4e8602eeb5115312c2), [commit 2752679](https://github.com/git/git/commit/275267937bdbb8611e8872d64adebe7587c6fa5a), [commit d1f87a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1f87a2d9c4877ada003c231b92de7560eab62ed), [commit 7190a67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7190a67eab181ebfbf61f4c8afaa3a149f685853), [commit ba931ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba931edd284f705d0c4b9af1f50f74a784fc6e34), [commit 0b91faa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b91faa010e438c4e0a58706573f3777da86ecde), [commit 31cf61a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31cf61a08008eb152247b16ee96811220f019fbd), [commit f7c3b4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7c3b4e2d8c16890c40c7e10e16cabb910f6b3ae), [commit 7188260](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7188260d1c9f4564dceaf45343abd55c5d9c6ded), [commit faa1df8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/faa1df86dc033ce1e6136ed89ad55df1bd479099), [commit 4eba1fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4eba1fe6156739e69e8cf3c1e84a9f050d91a884), [commit eb0be38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb0be38cc94d308fc114289e9555523ae34433b1), [commit 1cdde29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cdde296a5d3b0fd17a3fcd7a0869550b064fdce), [commit 5e242e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e242e63d0e9955a37268cc6b93b4e8fdedde07f), [commit a142f97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a142f978e7fbf7f4cbacb19c2475fbb82c29e5ca), [commit c8c5e43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8c5e43ac3f9a5b785faf16f10bb8e2c493606a4), [commit 9dc46e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9dc46e0268028059aecd140254bfe30277d04767), [commit d9c66f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9c66f0b5bfdf3fc2898b7baad1bb9a72bfd7bf7), [commit 348ae56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/348ae56cb2266d3294611112ae0368386124d720) (13 Aug 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit 8884cf1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8884cf15fb8ed83b2a1ec8bb91f060f20082b277) (13 Aug 2018) by [Thomas Rast (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 81eab68](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81eab6871e03869a8e47799c10ec1e1cb95ca34a), 20 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `range-diff`: show the diff between patches

> Just like `tbdiff`, we now show the diff between matching patches.
> **This is a "diff of two diffs"**, so it can be a bit daunting to read for the beginner.
>
> An alternative would be to display an interdiff, i.e. the hypothetical diff which is the result of first reverting the old diff and then applying the new diff.
>
> Especially when rebasing frequently, an interdiff is often not feasible,
> though: if the old diff cannot be applied in reverse (due to a moving
> upstream), an interdiff can simply not be inferred.
>
> This commit brings `range-diff` closer to feature parity with regard to tbdiff.
>
> To make `git range-diff` respect e.g. `color.diff.*` settings, we have to adjust `git_branch_config()` accordingly.
>
> Note: while `tbdiff` accepts the `--no-patches` option to suppress these diffs between patches, we prefer the `-s` (or `--no-patch`) option that is automatically supported via our use of `diff_opt_parse()`.
>
> And finally note: to support diff options, we have to call `parse_options()` such that it keeps unknown options, and then loop over those and let `diff_opt_parse()` handle them. After that loop, we have to call `parse_options()` again, to make sure that no unknown options are left.

---

And:

> ### `range-diff`: use dim/bold cues to improve dual color mode

> It *is* a confusing thing to look at a diff of diffs.
> All too easy is it to mix up whether the `-/+` markers refer to the "inner" or the "outer" diff, i.e. whether a `+` indicates that a line was added by either the old or the new diff (or both), or whether the new diff does something
> different than the old diff.
>
> To make things easier to process for normal developers, we introduced the dual color mode which colors the lines according to the commit diff, i.e. lines that are added by a commit (whether old, new, or both) are colored in green.
> In non-dual color mode, the lines would be colored according to the outer diff: if the old commit added a line, it would be colored red (because that line addition is only present in the first commit range that was specified on the command-line, i.e. the "old" commit, but not in the second commit range, i.e. the "new" commit).
>
> However, this dual color mode is still not making things clear enough, as we are looking at two levels of diffs, and we still only pick a color according to *one* of them (the outer diff marker is colored differently, of course, but in particular with deep indentation, it is easy to lose track of that outer diff marker's background color).
>
> Therefore, let's add another dimension to the mix.
> **Still use green/red/normal according to the commit diffs, but now also dim the lines that were only in the old commit, and use bold face for the lines
> that are only in the new commit.**
>
> That way, it is much easier not to lose track of, say, when we are looking at a line that was added in the previous iteration of a patch series but the new iteration adds a slightly different version: the obsolete change will be dimmed, the current version of the patch will be bold.
>
> At least this developer has a much easier time reading the range-diffs that way.

---

There are other ways than "`..`" for a single token to denote a "commit range", namely "`<rev>^!`" and "`<rev>^-<n>`", but "[`git range-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/77348b0e6e350ec81b3880f99c6077d165df2276/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff))</sup> did not understand them.

This is fixed with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021).

`<commit>^!` is a perfectly valid commit range, equivalent to
`<commit>^..<commit>`

See [commit 2cc543d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cc543deab38c188906c41e537dc5c7de98b93d7), [commit 359f0d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/359f0d754ab709c5a1ff3267bc117fb8559c62c2) (05 Feb 2021), and [commit 679b591](https://github.com/git/git/commit/679b5916cdafdcfa9fb36c31dbf53d7e4aa0af0b) (27 Jan 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 77348b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77348b0e6e350ec81b3880f99c6077d165df2276), 17 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`range-diff/format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/359f0d754ab709c5a1ff3267bc117fb8559c62c2): handle commit ranges other than `A..B`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In the [`SPECIFYING RANGES` section of gitrevisions[7]](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions), two ways are described to specify commit ranges that `range-diff` does not yet accept: "`<commit>^!`" and "`<commit>^-<n>`".
>
> Let's accept them, by parsing them via the revision machinery and looking for at least one interesting and one uninteresting revision in the resulting `pending` array.
>
> This also finally lets us reject arguments that *do* contain `..` but are not actually ranges, e.g. `HEAD^{/do.. match this}`.

And:

> ### [`range-diff(docs)`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cc543deab38c188906c41e537dc5c7de98b93d7): explain how to specify commit ranges
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> There are three forms, depending whether the user specifies one, two or three non-option arguments.
> We've never actually explained how this works in the manual, so let's explain it.

`git range-diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2cc543deab38c188906c41e537dc5c7de98b93d7/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt#L31-L41):

> There are three ways to specify the commit ranges:
>
> - `<range1> <range2>`: Either commit range can be of the form
>   `<base>..<rev>`, `<rev>^!` or `<rev>^-<n>`. See `SPECIFYING RANGES`
>   in linkgit:gitrevisions[7] for more details.
> - `<rev1>...<rev2>`. This is equivalent to
>   `<rev2>..<rev1> <rev1>..<rev2>`.
> - `<base> <rev1> <rev2>`: This is equivalent to `<base>..<rev1> <base>..<rev2>`.

---

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) allows passing a pathspec to `git range-diff`.

See [commit b757478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b75747829f4c277323c78b1c5973ad63ea038a2d), [commit 0087d7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0087d7dfbebf10f23394f32db3c283eb7ab03129), [commit edd6a31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/edd6a31f46096824f792f0fad5532c8d444c4c05) (26 Aug 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 428dce9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/428dce9f4d70b44b61c19c36f3dbe5b3f58aeba2), 09 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`range-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b75747829f4c277323c78b1c5973ad63ea038a2d): optionally accept pathspecs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> The [`git range-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b75747829f4c277323c78b1c5973ad63ea038a2d/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff))</sup> command can be quite expensive, which is not a surprise given that the underlying algorithm to match up pairs of commits between the provided two commit ranges has a cubic runtime.
>
> Therefore it makes sense to restrict the commit ranges as much as possible, to reduce the amount of input to that O(N^3) algorithm.
>
> In chatty repositories with wide trees, this is not necessarily possible merely by choosing commit ranges wisely.
>
> Let's give users another option to restrict the commit ranges: by providing a pathspec.
> That helps in repositories with wide trees because it is likely that the user has a good idea which subset of the tree they are actually interested in.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> git range-diff upstream/main upstream/seen HEAD -- range-diff.c
> ```
>
> This shows commits that are either in the local branch or in `seen`, but not in `main`, skipping all commits that do not touch [`range-diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b75747829f4c277323c78b1c5973ad63ea038a2d/range-diff.c).
>
> Note: Since we piggy-back the pathspecs onto the `other_arg` mechanism that was introduced to be able to pass through the `--notes` option to the revision machinery, we must now ensure that the `other_arg` array is appended at the end (the revision range must come before the pathspecs, if any).

`git range-diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b75747829f4c277323c78b1c5973ad63ea038a2d/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt#L15):

> ```
> [[--] <path>...]
> ```

`git range-diff` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b75747829f4c277323c78b1c5973ad63ea038a2d/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt#L23-L25):

> In the presence of `<path>` arguments, these commit ranges are limited accordingly.

Comment: This is great! Based on it, I wrote a new answer on [How to effectively review git submodule updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668461/how-to-effectively-review-git-submodule-updates/61668462).